# Custom Execution Strategy Error in VS2017 and Entity framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I'm reading "Building Web Applications with Visual Studio 2017" (by Philip Japikse, Kevin Grossnicklaus, and Ben Dewey) and am getting stuck. When trying to create a class for a custome execution strategy with Entity Framework Core I get error CR0246 "The type or namespace name 'ExecutionStrategyContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)"

The text only states that only System and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage are required references. The EF Core 2.0 documentation seems to match the text but I cannot get the error to go away.

Note: The book uses Core and EF 1.1 whereas I am using 2.0. But I don't see anything in any documentation that hints at this being the issue. The class is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SpyStore.DAL.EF
{
    public class MyExecutionStrategy : ExecutionStrategy
    {
        public MyExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyContext context) :
            base(context, ExecutionStrategy.DefaultMaxRetryCount, ExecutionStrategy.DefaultMaxDelay)
        {

        }

        public MyExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyContext context, int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxRetryDelay) :
            base(context, maxRetryCount, maxRetryDelay)
        {

        }

        protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

VS2017 is highlighting both instances of ExecutionStrategyContext as the issue. I've tried changing them to just 'ExecutionStrategy context' instead of 'ExecutionStrategyContext context' but I don't think this is what I want and I still get an error because my first parameter is context. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't provide a documentation link because at this time the related EF Core API documentation is not updated yet, but in v2.0 the `ExecutionStrategyContext` class has been replaced with `ExecutionStrategyDependencies` and the `ExecutionStrategy` class now has the following constructors:

```
protected ExecutionStrategy(DbContext context, int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxRetryDelay);

protected ExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies dependencies, int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxRetryDelay);
```

According to that, the updated sample should be something like this:

```
public class MyExecutionStrategy : ExecutionStrategy
{
    public MyExecutionStrategy(DbContext context) :
        this(context, DefaultMaxRetryCount, DefaultMaxDelay)
    {
    }

    public MyExecutionStrategy(DbContext context, int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxRetryDelay) :
        base(context, maxRetryCount, maxRetryDelay)
    {
    }

    public MyExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies dependencies) :
        this(dependencies, DefaultMaxRetryCount, DefaultMaxDelay)
    {
    }

    public MyExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies dependencies, int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxRetryDelay) :
        base(dependencies, maxRetryCount, maxRetryDelay)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```